# For Loop adding list of strings to NetCDF variable, only adding last value issue

Tags: python, string, for-loop, netcdf, python-xarray

I am creating a NetCDF file from many other ones and my only issue is grabbing a string value and writing it to a NetCDF variable. Right now, the code below can successfully write data (time, lat, lon, and other variables) but it is only taking the last value in my list of stations "S". for variable `station`. There's two ways to do this. One is reading and writing in a global attribute station name which I've listed below. I also have a populated list of strings that matches that same value. I've tried searching here but can't find it. Maybe it is in the `chartostring` and `stringtochar` commands? I got that working with another example on here, alebit without any looping. I think I need additional code to make sure it writes all stations names, not just the last one.

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

# create list of station names for dataset writing (listObsFile is list of all NetCDF files) 
S = []
for i in listObsFiles:
    if i.endswith('0h2021.nc'):
        statID = i[8:13]
        S.append(statID)

waveObsNC = nc.Dataset(file, 'w')

nstrings = waveObsNC.createDimension('nstrings', len(S)) 
nchars = waveObsNC.createDimension('nchars', 5) 

station = waveObsNC.createVariable('station', 'S5', ('station',))
v = waveObsNC.createVariable('v', 'S1', ('nchars'))

for i in range(len(S)):
     File = xr.open_dataset(filepath+'saveWave'+ str(S[i]) +'h2021.nc')
        
     # Read in station data, deconstruct and rebuild to create valid NetCDF variable
     st = File.attrs['station']
     datain = np.array([st],dtype='S5')
     v[:] = nc.stringtochar(datain1)
     station[:] = nc.chartostring(v[:])  
       
# waveObsNC.close()
```

Output for the above code for `station[:]`:

```
print(station[:])    
array(['51210', '51210', '51210', '51210', '51210', '51210', '51210',
       '51210', '51210', '51210', '51210'], dtype=object)
```

An alternative to above is `st = S[i]` which produces the same station string value. Here's a look at that list:

```
print(S)
['41010', '41040', '41110', '42060', '42360', '44020', '44030', '44090', '46060', '51000', '51210']
```

but again the same error:

```
print(station[:])    
array(['51210', '51210', '51210', '51210', '51210', '51210', '51210',
       '51210', '51210', '51210', '51210'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was overthinking it. If I was reading a list of strings as in the list `S`, then yes I would need to do `stringtochar` and `chartostring` to deconstruct and create a VLEN string variable value. But, doing it where you grab the station name from the global attribute station name means it's obviously a properly formatted string already to be used inside a NetCDF file. So, in the loop, indexing the station variable with `i` and equaling it to the attribute station name works great, i.e.:

```
for i in range(len(S)):
     File = xr.open_dataset(filepath+'saveWave'+ str(S[i]) +'h2021.nc')
        
     # Read in station data, deconstruct and rebuild to create valid NetCDF variable
     station[i] = File.attrs['station']
```